# AWS Cognito: Google Login find the email address

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

Once the cognito-id is created for a user logging via. google, how to find the email id of the user.

[image]

As shown in the above picture, I can find the cognito-id, but couldn't find any other information that google could have supplied when the user logged in.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance,

Comment: Is there an api using which the additional info could be read from the server? Thank you

Answer (score 3):

First make sure you provide `email` in scopes. Usually the scope is defined as `profile email openid`.

Next you have to "Configure attribute mapping" which is on the bottom right of the "Identity providers" section. There you can map Google's `email` attribute to the `Email` attribute of the user pool.

You'd probably have to remove users from the pool that logged in prior to the additional configuration to properly fetch the attributes. You can do this by clicking on the google user in the user pool then click "Disable" then "Delete". For example, I couldn't see the picture attribute of a google user until I removed my user from the pool and logged in again.

You should now be able to see the email attribute (and other properly configured) when you click on the user. You should also be able to see these attributes when you decode the `id_token` and when you call the `<AUTH_DOMAIN>/oauth2/userInfo` endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Cognito leverages these tokens to sign in users, but doesn't store any additional metadata against the user. It doesn't track any of it, so you won't see it there. To do so, you'd need to grab it from Google during sign in, and either store it in Cognito sync or in an external datastore (e.g. a dynamo table keyed by identity id).